# How can i initialiaze objects in a rest server with jersey (java)?

Tags: java, web-applications, jersey

I have a dumb question. I have got a java web application and a rest interfaces with jersey. Where can I put a initialization  block of code?

For example, I have got a singleton, with a method "createInstance". How can i execute "createInstance" method once time the rest server is running. Is there something like "Main()" to place initialization stuff?

I have got also servlets in the proyects but those are executing when a user open the webpage.

I want to know if exist any place to put my initialization code.

Answer (score 6):

Finally i found the solution:

For execute initialization code i can create a implementation of "ServletContextListener".

In this way i do this:

```
package foopackage;

...
public class ServletContextClass implements ServletContextListener
{  

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) 
    {        
            ...     
    }


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) 
    {
           ...
    }
}
```

To use this listener after the application server initialization it is necessary to put this in the web.xml.

```
 <listener>
     <listener-class>foopackage.ServletContextClass</listener- class>
 </listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what you mean by "initialize objects". I guess the obvious answer is that you initialize an object wherever you need it.

If you need to create a Singleton you would create it as you would do with any other singleton in Java, using a static filed or an enum; and you would get an instance of it inside the one of your REST methods. For instance

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getData() {
   Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
   String result = singleton.domSomething();
   return result;
}
```

If what you want is to make your resource (web service) a singleton, then you can do so by extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application and then, depending on the JAX-RS implementation and server that you are using, you may need to configure your web.xml to initialize your REST services using this Application definition. This class has method named `getSingletons()` that you can extend to provide singletons of your resources.

Comment: Not, a singleton is not valid for me. I know that that exist. The reason is that the "getInstance" takes too time. I want to do some intialization code when the rest server finishes the initialization, before to open the web services to the clients.

Answer (score -1):

Rest resource is just like any other class.
You can use the constructor to initialize your objects.

Comment: No, sorry. I need to initialice some objects before to open web services to outside.

Comment: You can create a class that all your resources will extend, which will have the initialization code in some static block or something.